# Expression is too complex?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I have a report running of the SQL below. Runs fine when the values are hard coded. However when I supply the values through a form that accepts dates I get the error

**This expression is typed incorrectly, or it is too complex to be evaluated. For example, a numeric expression may contain too many complicated elements. Try simplyfying the expression by assigning parts of the expression to variables**

In addition, I also get prompted for the Workdate. What is wrong with my approach?

```
SELECT Employees.EmployeeId, Employees.EmployeeName, TasksEntries.Project,
TasksEntries.Task, SUM(TimeTracker.WorkHours) AS TotalWorkHours
FROM Employees INNER JOIN (TasksEntries INNER JOIN TimeTracker ON  
(TasksEntries.EmployeeId=TimeTracker.EmployeeId) AND 
(TasksEntries.TaskID=TimeTracker.TaskId)) ON 
(Employees.EmployeeId=TimeTracker.EmployeeId) AND 
(Employees.EmployeeId=TasksEntries.EmployeeId)
 WHERE TimeTracker.WorkDate>="#" & Forms!frmManagerReport!txtMgrRptStartDate 
 & "#" And TimeTracker.WorkDate<="#" & 
 Forms!frmManagerReport!txtMgrRptEndDate & "#"
 GROUP BY Employees.EmployeeId, Employees.EmployeeName, 
 TasksEntries.Project, TasksEntries.Task;
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked in Access for years, but I hope this will help.  1 - bad expression - Catch the built expression in the debugger just before it executes, but after you've collected the values.  Then you can examine and run the built string directly in Access.  You might be able to see the error better that way.  2 - prompted for Workdate - probably because the query doesn't really have it.  Is it case-sensitive?  Are Forms!frmManagerReport!txtMgrRptStartDate and Forms!frmManagerReport!txtMgrRptEndDate actually filled in and a valid date?

Answer (score 0):

You have combined all your join conditions together, which won't work.

Instead, code them with the join to which they belong:

```
SELECT e.EmployeeId, e.EmployeeName, te.Project, te.Task, SUM(TimeTracker.WorkHours) AS TotalWorkHours
FROM Employees e
JOIN TasksEntries te ON te.EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId
JOIN TimeTracker tt ON tt.EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId
  AND te.TaskID = tt.TaskID
WHERE tt.WorkDate BETWEEN "#" & Forms!frmManagerReport!txtMgrRptStartDate & "#" AND "#" & Forms!frmManagerReport!txtMgrRptEndDate & "#"
GROUP BY e.EmployeeId, e.EmployeeName, te.Project, te.Task;
```

I also added table aliases and introduced a BETWEEN to make the query more readable.

Comment: One thing I was able to resolve is the result coming out correctly. The query did not need the "#" signs. However I still get the prompt for TimeTracker.Workdate.